# Why class instance itself has no public constructor?

Tags: java, reflection

While reading Reflection API i got this **"Every Java Type has a class Instance And the class instance itself has no public Constructor"** .

Now this is really confusing for me. Because what i have read till now says . All classes have constructor even when we don't specify any, we get constructor by default (even if the class is static) once we create its instance. Can someone explain me this in simple word

(to show even static class has constructor)

```
public class Reader1 {
    private int pageNumber;

    private class ReaderName1{
    public int getPage(){
        return pageNumber;
    }
    }
    static class ReaderFound{

    }
}
```

using javap

```
class Reader1$ReaderFound {
          Reader1$ReaderFound();
        }
```

Comment: Please link to the document where you read that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
 i don't have link i was viewing this on Safari book Online 
Java Reflection LiveLessons (Video Training)

By: Paul Anderson

Publisher: Addison-Wesley

Pub. Date: February 15, 2012

ISBN-13: 978-0-13-303811-8

ISBN-10: 0-13-303811-4

Comment: I feel like the quote is referring to the `Class` class.

Comment: yes it's referring to same class Class

Answer (score 0):

It says: *no `public` constructor*. That doesn't mean it has no constructor at all. It does have a `private` constructor, which you can also create, as below given class, which also doesn't have a `public` constructor.

```
class Test {
    private Test() { }
}
```

Comment: That is my doubt even because in java docs .. its defined this way 

public final class Class<T>
extends Object
implements Serializable, GenericDeclaration, Type, AnnotatedElement

Since the class is public how still it's not having public constructor ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand A public class shouldn't always have `public` constructor. A `public` class is visible everywhere, just that it's `private` constructor is not. Basically that is how you write a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

"Every Java Type has a class Instance And the class instance itself has no public Constructor" that's means the java.lang.Class has no public constructor because Only the JVM can create the java.lang.Class instance ,and every class Java Type has a java.lang.Class instance.i think that is reason why you were confused.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can suppress a `public` constructor by defining it `private` in the inheriting class - for `Class` this means:

```
public final class Class<T> {
  private Class() {
    //this constructor is private, no other constructor exists or will be generated
  }
}
```

To create an instance of class there exist some factory methods, like `Class.forName`.

Answer (score 0):

Directly cited from the official website. I hope it can help you.

> The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class objects.
>   **Class has no public constructor**. Instead a Class object is constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine when a class loader invokes one of the defineClass methods and passes the bytes of a class file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html